# Do we need ergodic-stationarity of the response variable in OLS spline regression?

Tags: regression, nonlinear-regression, stationarity, splines, ergodic

I was wondering if we need the response variable to be ergodic stationarity when estimating an OLS spline regression. My intuition tells me that it's not needed but I would like to have a confirmation regarding it.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've never heard of ergodicity being a necessary condition for the fulfilment of any property of OLS estimators. What motivated this question of yours?

Comment: For example in time series analysis when dealing with big set of data, the ergodicity is a sort of weak "independence" between observations. In ols we need the observations to be i.i.d. but since in time series that is just imposible because of the "memory " of the series sometimes ergodicity is required. At least according to all my econometric books

Comment: In OLS we need the erros to be iid, not the dependent variable.

Comment: The ergodic-stationarity of the dependent and the independent variables allows us to proof the ergodicity and stationarity of the error term